# Would does stroke-dashoffset glitch on Safari? Both mobile and Mac

Tags: javascript, css-animations, css-transitions, addeventlistener, stroke-dasharray

I have an animation using an svg.
You can see the site here: https://www.demo.simplerwebsites.com

Codepen for just animation: https://codepen.io/webbchris2001/pen/wvojzwE

The animation is meant to 'write the text'.
It works fine on Firefox and Chrome. However for some reason on safari it glitches and seems to blink.
This is also the case on safari on the phone.

When I add from{stroke-dashoffset: 100%;} It then causes the same glitch across all browsers.
I know that negative values are not accepted on Safari for stroke-dashoffset however I do not believe there would be any negative values here?

Javascript:

```
const masks = ['natur-n', 'natur-a', 'natur-t', 'natur-u', 'natur-r', 'comma', 'kunst-k', 'kunst-u', 'kunst-n', 'kunst-s', 'kunst-t', 'and-a', 'and-n', 'and-d', 'design-d', 'design-e', 'design-s', 'design-i', 'design-g', 'design-n'];

    masks.forEach((mask, index, el) => {
        const id = `#${mask}-path`;
        let path = document.querySelector(id);
        const length = path.getTotalLength();
        path.style.strokeDasharray = length;
        path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
    });
```

Css:

```
        .marketing-lab .mask {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #fff;
          stroke-miterlimit: 10;
          stroke-dashoffset: 100%;
        }

        @keyframes strokeOffset {
          to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
          }
        }
        #natur-n-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s ease-in-out forwards;
        }
        #natur-a-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 0.2s;
        }
        #natur-t-path{
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 0.4s;
        }
        #natur-u-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 0.6s;
        }
        #natur-r-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 0.8s;
        }
        #comma-path{
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 1.0s;
        }
        #kunst-k-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 1.2s;
        }
        #kunst-u-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 1.4s;
        }
        #kunst-n-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 1.6s;
        }
        #kunst-s-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 1.8s;
        }
        #kunst-t-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 2.0s;
        }
        #and-a-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 2.2s;
        }
        #and-n-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 2.4s;
        }
        #and-d-path {
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 2.6s;
        }
        #design-d-path{
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 2.8s;
        }
        #design-e-path{
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 3.0s;
        }
        #design-s-path{
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 3.2s;
        }
        #design-i-path{
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 3.4s;
        }
        #design-g-path{
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 3.6s;
        }
        #design-n-path{
          animation: strokeOffset 0.2s linear forwards 3.8s;
        }
```

Edit:
It turns out its due this piece of javascript that I also have on the page for a carousel. However I cannot understand why??

```
let size = carousel_imgs[0].clientWidth;
```

Comment: I can see the glitching - a sort of 'stuttering' - on your website (Safari on iPad), but if I run just the SVG and its animations in a separate program it is smooth - so is there something in your website surrounding the SVG that causes the problem?

Comment: @AHaworth It SVG is just in a divr with this css .svg-container {
   height: 142px;
   position: absolute;
   top: calc(50% - 16px);
   left: calc(50% - 12px);
   transform: translate(-50%);
   width: 80vw;
   z-index: 99;
  }

Comment: @AHaworth To me it seems like it has to be the animation frames as I can recreate the glitching in chrome by adding a 'from' to the keyframes. Maybe there is some sort of default setting in safari that isn't there in chrome/firefox?

Comment: Strange. I put the svg into the div you gave and it's still nice and smooth on Safari/iPad, but your website isn't. Interesting about the 'from' I'll try it.

Comment: @AHaworth I forgot to add the javascript to the post. Added it now